# Dependencies from private bitbucket repo don't restore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bitbucket, bower, visual-studio-2015

I have an asp.net MVC 5 project that I have setup to work with bower, grunt and npm that work perfectly fine in Visual Studio 2013. Having tried to load the same project in Visual Studio 2015 (RTM), I'm finding that as VS 2015 attempts to restore the bower dependencies on load it doesn't complete.

Through a process of elimination of my `bower.json` dependencies, I've found that public github based dependencies work perfectly fine, e.g.

`"zip.js": "git://github.com/gildaslormeau/zip.js.git#1bead0a3bb9d2e50ea34094bbfe9bb6a2196939a"`

However when I include a private bitbucket repo using a url such as `git@bitbucket.org:{owner}/{repo}.git#1.0.0` in my `bower.json` dependencies then the issue reappears. Running git commands via the console with these private repos works as expected.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

It would appear the issue relates to visual studio 2015 not loading the relevant SSH keys.  Running "bower install ./bower.json" inside a posh-git console works.  Not sure how to get Visual Studio 2015 to use my SSH keys!

Comment: Is Bower providing any error messages when the install fails? These will show up in the Output window in Visual Studio. (You might need to switch "Show output from:" to "Bower/NPM".) The Output window will also show the full Bower command that VS tried to execute, so you can try that in a console window outside of VS. That may provide more information as well.

Comment: No errors, just stuck whilst restoring dependencies.

I tried the full bower command as follows:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External> .\bower.cmd install ..." and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is SSH keys, Bower is probably blocking and waiting for you to enter your passphrase, but VS doesn't have the capability to respond to the prompt. That would explain why it gets stuck while restoring.

I was able to reproduce that problem by following the directions at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git to set up a bitbucket account using SSH for login, and configure Git Bash to connect to it on startup. Bower commands would then work from Git Bash, but not in Visual Studio.

Then, I was able to work around the problem by launching Visual Studio from the Git Bash prompt. That seemed to put Visual Studio in the environment that was already configured to use the passphrase that was entered when the shell started, so Bower didn't need to prompt for it.

In this case, I used the following format for the repo path:

```
"{package-name}": "git@bitbucket.org:{user}/{repo}.git#1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this syntax for the private bitbucket repro?  We tried this internally, witch success:

```
"{packageName}": "https://{owner}@bitbucket.org/{owner}/{repo}.git#{version}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue remains! :(